# SharePoint 2010 Custom web service issues

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can someone move this to Sharepoint.Stackexchange please?

I have created a custom web service. I can access the WSDL file and i can access the service and click on the method via the browser. Very simple Hello world web service nothing amazing just simples! See the code below.

```
[WebServiceBinding( ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1), WebService(Namespace = "SImpleWebService")]
    class SimpleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Typical web method")]
        public string[] HelloWorld()
        {
            List<string> pow = new List<string>();
            pow.Add("Hello World");
            pow.Add("Hi");
            return pow.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The web service is deployed to the _layouts and _vti_bin and both are giving me the same error.

When i use fiddler i can see that the request is being sent from my ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender and i am getting an error!

it's a 401 unauthorised error.

Loop back is disabled.

What am i missing?!

Many Thanks!

Comment: If you are using SharePoint 2010, you should really follow the [guidelines from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx). It is far more easier to deploy the web services using a custom svc file, with its code using the auto publication feature of SharePoint (endpoints are automatically generated using the `BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpointAttribute`. That said, do you know there is a [sharepoint dedicated StackExchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I've edited the Q to ask someone to move the thread just before you posted, Yes i tried the svc route and managed to get a working service to a cosole app but struggle to get it to work within a web part. I posted about this but no one answered so i thought i would try this route also to see if it was any easier. Cheers for the link i will have a read :)

Comment: Can you check what is exactly the error? In the IIS log (it's the only way to find it), you will find the `substatus`. This will tell you if it's a 401.1, 401.2, ... error. This is important because the solutions differs.

Answer (score 0):

Specify them separately

[WebService(Namespace = "SImpleWebService")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]